# simple $http json tab-app blank page - ionic

Tags: json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to build a simple `$http` application that takes a local `JSON` file and represents it.

The application works just fine when I access it on `myApp>www>index.html` file but when I go to `templates/tab-dash` (which is also viewed when I open index.html on the `python` server) I just get a blank page.

tab-dash code:

```
    <div ng-app="starter" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
          {{1 + 2}}
          <input type="text" ng-model="person.Name" />
          <input type="text" ng-model="person.lastName" />
          <input type="button" ng-click="addPerson(person)" />
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="person in people">
                {{person.Name}} {{person.Description}}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

js/app.js code:

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
.state('tab.dash', {
  url: '/dash',
  views: {
    'tab-dash': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    }
  }
})
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/tab-dash");
})

app.controller('AppCtrl', function( $scope, $http) {
    var app = this;
    $http.get('webtest.json')
      .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.people = data;
      })

    app.addPerson = function(person) {

    }
})
```

Edit:ill add the json file which is in www folder:

```
[
{"id": "0","Name": "Items 0", "Description": "Description 0"},
{"id": "1","Name": "Items 1", "Description": "Description 1"},
{"id": "2","Name": "Items 2", "Description": "Description 2"},
{"id": "3","Name": "Items 3", "Description": "Description 3"},
{"id": "4","Name": "Items 4", "Description": "Description 4"},
{"id": "5","Name": "Items 5", "Description": "Description 5"},
{"id": "6","Name": "Items 6", "Description": "Description 6"},
{"id": "7","Name": "Items 7", "Description": "Description 7"},
{"id": "8","Name": "Items 8", "Description": "Description 8"},
{"id": "9","Name": "Items 9", "Description": "Description 9"},
{"id": "10","Name": "Items 10", "Description": "Description 10"},
{"id": "11","Name": "Items 11", "Description": "Description 11"},
{"id": "12","Name": "Items 12", "Description": "Description 12"},
{"id": "13","Name": "Items 13", "Description": "Description 13"},
{"id": "14","Name": "Items 14", "Description": "Description 14"},
{"id": "15","Name": "Items 15", "Description": "Description 15"},
{"id": "16","Name": "Items 16", "Description": "Description 16"},
{"id": "17","Name": "Items 17", "Description": "Description 17"},
{"id": "18","Name": "Items 18", "Description": "Description 18"},
{"id": "19","Name": "Items 19", "Description": "Description 19"},
{"id": "20","Name": "Items 20", "Description": "Description 20"},
{"id": "21","Name": "Items 21", "Description": "Description 21"},
{"id": "22","Name": "Items 22", "Description": "Description 22"},
{"id": "23","Name": "Items 23", "Description": "Description 23"},
{"id": "24","Name": "Items 24", "Description": "Description 24"},
{"id": "25","Name": "Items 25", "Description": "Description 25"},
{"id": "26","Name": "Items 26", "Description": "Description 26"},
{"id": "27","Name": "Items 27", "Description": "Description 27"},
{"id": "28","Name": "Items 28", "Description": "Description 28"},
{"id": "29","Name": "Items 29", "Description": "Description 29"},
{"id": "30","Name": "Items 30", "Description": "Description 30"},
{"id": "31","Name": "Items 31", "Description": "Description 31"},
{"id": "32","Name": "Items 32", "Description": "Description 32"},
{"id": "33","Name": "Items 33", "Description": "Description 33"},
{"id": "34","Name": "Items 34", "Description": "Description 34"},
{"id": "35","Name": "Items 35", "Description": "Description 35"},
{"id": "36","Name": "Items 36", "Description": "Description 36"},
{"id": "37","Name": "Items 37", "Description": "Description 37"},
{"id": "38","Name": "Items 38", "Description": "Description 38"},
{"id": "39","Name": "Items 39", "Description": "Description 39"},
{"id": "40","Name": "Items 40", "Description": "Description 40"},
{"id": "41","Name": "Items 41", "Description": "Description 41"},
{"id": "42","Name": "Items 42", "Description": "Description 42"},
{"id": "43","Name": "Items 43", "Description": "Description 43"},
{"id": "44","Name": "Items 44", "Description": "Description 44"},
{"id": "45","Name": "Items 45", "Description": "Description 45"}
]
```

Comment: You should really clean up your code when posting it here.

Comment: of yeha sorry for that, cleaned it up now. just wanted you to see the built in ionic code

Answer (score 0):

You only have 1 route in your application, which is `/dash`.

The following line

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/tab-dash");
```

Is trying to redirect you to a non-existing `URL`, `/tab/tab-dash`.

It should look like this:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dash");
```

Comment: still showing a blank page and i can't even see the <back button, title and tabs switchers that are should be automaticly showed when i open index.html on python server. the only error i get is  404 cordava not found which is a beacause its on dekstop and not on the android...

Comment: i think i know what the problem is: when i load 0.0.0.0:8000 on my the url is changes to:http://localhost:8000/#/dash. so i think the problem is that its /#/dash where it should be /templates/dash. no idea how to fix this.